# How can I test with jest an if statement within a reducer?

Tags: redux, immutability, jestjs

I want to test this reducer but is pretty unclear to me how to run a test on a if statement.

```
case REMOVE_NOTIFICATION: {
    if (state.getIn(['notification', 'message']) === action.message) {
        return initialState;
    }
    return state;
}

case TICK_NOTIFICATION:
    return state.setIn(['notification', 'timer'], 
    state.getIn(['notification', 'timer']) - 1);

default:
    return state;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is an implementation detail and should not be tested. You want to test expected behaviour. You put an action on the reducer and expect a new state to be resolved. You want to test all the expected behaviours and not just one. This ensures you that changing an implementation detail does not break your test.